# Codeigniter Database Error : 1064 Using MySQL and maybe some session config error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, xampp

I'm currently using Codeigniter 3.xx and I trying to make a multilevel login using session checking. I got some tutorial from another website, but there's an error with query.
By the way this is for the controler :

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function cek_login() {
        $data = array('nip' => $this->input->post('nip'),
                        'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );
        $this->load->model('user_m'); 
        $hasil = $this->user_m->cek_user($data);
        if ($hasil->num_rows() == 1) {
            foreach ($hasil->result() as $sess) {
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'Sudah Loggin';
                $sess_data['nip'] = $sess->nip;
                $sess_data['akses'] = $sess->akses;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }
            if ($this->session->userdata('akses')=='admin') {
                redirect('admin');
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('akses')=='member') {
                redirect('user');
            }       
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Gagal login: Cek username, password!');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

This is the model for the controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User_m extends CI_Model {

        public function cek_user($data) {
            $query = $this->db->get_where(`pegawai`, $data);
            return $query;
        }

    }

?>
```

Then I got this error :

**Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `nip` = '21212121' AND `password` = 'user'' at line 2
SELECT * WHERE `nip` = '21212121' AND `password` = 'user'
Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/simpeg/application/models/User_m.php
Line Number: 7**

The things that I know I don't use MariaDB Engine for this table, and it should be logged in as user if that run correctly.
Can anybody explain what was the wrong with this syntax?
By the way I'm using **newest XAMPP for PHP 7 and Codeigniter** in this project

**UPDATE**
After I tried some code, I thought that I have some problem with the session configuration.
This is my config.php for session:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

And this is my configuration in Session.php in system folder :

```
class CI_Session {

    var $sess_encrypt_cookie        = FALSE;
    var $sess_use_database          = FALSE;
    var $sess_table_name            = '';
    var $sess_expiration            = 7200;
    var $sess_expire_on_close       = FALSE;
    var $sess_match_ip              = FALSE;
    var $sess_match_useragent       = TRUE;
    var $sess_cookie_name           = 'ci_session';
    var $cookie_prefix              = '';
    var $cookie_path                = '';
    var $cookie_domain              = '';
    var $cookie_secure              = FALSE;
    var $sess_time_to_update        = 300;
    var $encryption_key             = '';
    var $flashdata_key              = 'flash';
    var $time_reference             = 'time';
    var $gc_probability             = 5;
    var $userdata                   = array();
    var $CI;
    var $now;
```

In the new version of Codeigniter (which one I use), whenever I tried to autoload session there always asked me to put some encryption key for the session, so after I put the encryption key there's an error in the query about session like this:
**Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `last_activity` = 1455761673, `user_data` = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1
UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1455761673, `user_data` = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"nip\";s:10:\"1234567890\";}' WHERE `session_id` = '316bdf2f67b16beafbe30b56bca3833d'
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 306**

Comment: print your `query` by using `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`  and try to run that query in db console. it will be easy to debug.

Comment: @Kamran Did you mean to change the return with `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but, I've found the answer for my problem...
After I tried to download newest Codeigniter again, and replace it in my project, and re-config my project, in result my query was read and successful executed, but the session didn't. So I tried to debug my code for 2 days, and I found (just about 15 minutes ago) there's something strange in my controller for admin/user, there wasn't `<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` but instead `<?php session_start();` so I changed it and problem solved. Oh if anyone found

> libraries/Session.php

**DELETE IT!**

That's the first reason that I have this error

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE nip = '21212121' AND password = 'user'' at
>   line 2 SELECT * WHERE nip = '21212121' AND password = 'user' Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/simpeg/application/models/User_m.php Line Number: 7

Thanks for you all who helped me... :D

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question but still the right answer is that you had to read the config.php file carefully and you would understand that you missed some points of the configuration to save sessions the right way.

```
/* 'sess_save_path'
|
|   The location to save sessions to, driver dependent.
|
|   For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
|   WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
|
|   For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
|   Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
|
|   IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!
*/
```

Your session path was not right!

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
 $query = $this->db->get_where(`pegawai`, $data);
 return $query;
```

to

```
 $this->db->where($data);
 $query=$this->db->get('pegawai');
 return $query;
```

Comment: sorry but there's another error :

**Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `last_activity` = 1455757641, `user_data` = 'a:4:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1

UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1455757641, `user_data` = 'a:4:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"logged_in\";s:12:\"Sudah Loggin\";s:3:\"nip\";s:10:\"1234567890\";s:5:\"akses\";s:5:\"admin\";}' WHERE `session_id` = 'f4f0eae180cfca66af04e6cd2dbb2f5a'

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 306**

Comment: before that, there's an error because I didn't make a key for encryption session, but after I make the key, there's an error just like that

Comment: I use backtick to call pegawai table and there's another error just like the first...
It's realy I have an error in session?

Comment: delete records from ci_sessions table

Comment: how can I delete it?

Comment: select database and perform query : delete from ci_sessions

Comment: check and let me know

Comment: I had check my database, but there is not any table named ci_sessions, (well actually I didn't make one). So I tried to reverse anything that had any connection with this, until I decided to reverse all my project...
-_-
Actually I have a backup, and now with the backup I can't save anything into session, it said : 
** Undefined property: Auth::$session** and the reference line that has the error is about `set_userdata` so I thought that I can't set session data