# Codeigniter, cannot make a session?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I have the a same problem like in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451518/codeigniter-database-error-1064-using-mysql-and-maybe-some-session-config-erro), and now I thought that I have a problem with the session, because the query to my database is working well except for making session in this problem.
Well the error said :

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `last_activity` = 1455780614, `user_data` = 'a:4:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1

UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1455780614, `user_data` = 'a:4:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"logged_in\";s:12:\"Sudah Loggin\";s:3:\"nip\";s:8:\"21212121\";s:5:\"akses\";s:4:\"user\";}' WHERE `session_id` = '2e72650df8541dcc3334394cfb7eef37'

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 306
```

That happen after I autoloaded the session and insert the encryption key. This is my controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_m');
    }
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function cek_login() {
        $data = array('nip' => $this->input->post('nip', TRUE),
                        'password' => $this->input->post('password', TRUE)
            );

        $hasil = $this->user_m->cek_user($data);
        if ($hasil->num_rows()==1) {
            foreach ($hasil->result() as $sess) {
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'Sudah Loggin';
                $sess_data['nip'] = $sess->nip;
                $sess_data['akses'] = $sess->akses;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }
            
            if ($this->session->userdata('akses')=='admin') {
                redirect('admin');
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('akses')=='member') {
                redirect('user');
            }       
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Gagal login: Cek nip, password!');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

And this is my model :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User_m extends CI_Model {
        public function cek_user($data) {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('pegawai', $data);
            return $query;      
        }

    }

?>
```

I'm doing this for make a multi-user login, but the couldn't make a session.
I'm using **XAMPP 7.0.2** and **Codeigniter 3.0.4** for this project.

Comment: Check your config file, maybe your forgot to set the session table name

Comment: @Gwendal there isn't any config for session table name in config.php

Comment: eh, I found it in system/library/session.php but still didn't help

Comment: Try to add `$config['sess_table_name'] = 'your_table';` in the config file, maybe it'll help

Comment: Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086348/how-i-can-set-a-session-in-codeigniter-3-database

Comment: @Gwendal I took a look at your suggestion link, and my session was recorded into the database, but it didn't record any session userdata. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'Sudah Loggin';
                $sess_data['nip'] = $sess->nip;
                $sess_data['akses'] = $sess->akses;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);


change this to given way

     $sess_data = array(
                   'logged_in'  => 'Sudah Loggin',
                   'nip'     => $sess->nip,
                   'akses' =>  $sess->akses
               );

    $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
```

Comment: did you load session in autoload ?

Comment: also commend  /*  'nip'     => $sess->nip,
                   'akses' =>  $sess->akses */ and check

Comment: I had load session in autoload, but I didn't try the comment suggestion, lemme try it first

Comment: I had tried the comment, and it show a blank page on browser and didn't redirect to the page I want. I tried use the session configuration from @Gwendal in the comment upside, and the session was recorded in database but it doesn't save any session data, so it always redirect to login page but the session was recorded in the database

Comment: so the session values successfully inserts in db.. But the sessions are not set. right ?

Comment: yes, the sessions was recorded but not with session userdata...
I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code

```
public function login()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $a      =   $this->input->post('email');
    $b      =   trim($this->input->post('password'));
    $b1     =   md5($b);
    $c      =   1;
    $data   =   $this->userdata->userlogin($a,$b1,$c);
    if($data)
    {
        echo true;
        foreach ($data as $login)
        {
            $uid=$this->session->set_userdata('logId',$login->usr_id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid username or password..!!!!";
        $a=$this->input->post('email');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try this now

Comment: By the way, what does $c do? It's just for login checking or what?

Comment: that is for checking status.the registered users status is set to 1. so checking status is 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but, I've found the answer for my problem...
After I tried to download newest Codeigniter again, and replace it in my project, and re-config my project, in result my query was read and successful executed, but the session didn't. So I tried to debug my code for 2 days, and I found (just about 15 minutes ago) there's something strange in my controller for admin/user, there wasn't `<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` but instead `<?php session_start();` so I changed it and problem solved. Oh if anyone found :

> libraries/Session.php

**DELETE IT!**

That's the first reason that I have this error :

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE nip = '21212121' AND password = 'user'' at
>   line 2 SELECT * WHERE nip = '21212121' AND password = 'user' Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/simpeg/application/models/User_m.php Line Number: 7

Thanks for you all who helped me... :D

Answer (score 0):

Error Number: 1064

I worked on this more than 5 hours.
all  functionality are working fine without session login, but problem with login and session.
finally i changed my system folder with latest CI 3.1.
Just open 
https://codeigniter.com/download

download complete CI3.x and extract do copy system folder from it and replace system folder with your previous system folder with it.
Please keep backup of previous system folder for reference.